# htaccess wordpress redirect directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already have some url redirect rule in my root htaccess so after following the step to give wordpress its own directory everything work well apart that my old url redirection/rewrite  don't work any more.

old htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule   dailylife/(.*)\.html dailylife.php?d=$1
```

new one with wordpress directory

```
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
RewriteRule   dailylife/(.*)\.html dailylife.php?d=$1
```

any help most welcome

Comment: Is the `dailylife stuff also in `/news/` folder?

Comment: put the dailylife rules on top.. and out of `# BEGIN WordPress`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your old rules *before* wordpress' routing rules:

```
RewriteBase /news/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule dailylife/(.*)\.html /dailylife.php?d=$1 [L]

RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
```